# Filter ordering with spring security and spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to use spring security to secure a rest/stateless api using JWT tokens. From the research I've been seeing, it involves turning off the spring security session management and then adding some custom filters to handle the user logging in as well as checking for the jwt token.

The problem I'm having is that once i add a filter, it's run on every instead of just the endpoints I want it on. I need to open up the login endpoint as well as a few others that will facilitate enrollment and reference data that doesn't need to be secured.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/user").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ;
    }
}
```

All StatelessAuthenticationFilter does is print "in here". I'm only expecting to see that message print when you go to localhost:8080/api/order, but i see it show up when you go to localhost:8080/api/user.

Is there a way to get this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you configured, the `HttpSecurity` will be applied to all the URLs including the user endpoint. 
 `authorizeRequests() .antMatchers("/api/user").permitAll()` line won't prevent "user" endpoint from authentication filter being called.
It just says that any authenticated user can call it.
You need to apply the filter to "order" endpoint only. Like this:
`http .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/user") .and() .authorizeRequests()`.

Comment: I tried that out and it worked! I also saw that you could override the configure(Websecurity) method and use the ignoring() method to ignore endpoints.  I'm not really sure which way is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

@tsolakp's answer sorta works for me. I ended up overriding the

configure(Websecurity) method though

```
 @Override
  public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/api/user");
  }

@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
        .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    ;
  }
```